# Как реализовать метод wait()?

Tags: java

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. В Java полный новичок, это моя проба "корявой" реализации MVC. Есть метод в котором необходимо "подождать" пока с GUI придет информация о нажатой кнопке, и только потом продолжить выполнение метода, как реализовать метод wait?

```
import java.util.*;

public class KNBGameStarter {


public static void main (String[] args){
    KNBGameStarter game = new KNBGameStarter();
    KNBGui gui = new KNBGui();


    gui.guiStarter();
    game.gameLogic();
}


    private void gameLogic() {
        KNBanalyzer a = new KNBanalyzer();
        KNBstrategy s = new KNBstrategy();
        KNBController controller = new KNBController();


        int round = 0;
        int lastplm = 0;
        int lastpcm = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (round == 0 || a.whoIsWinning()) {
                s.sRandom();
            } if (round > 1 && a.isLpmRepeat(round-1)){
                s.sAntiRepeat (lastplm);
            } if (round > 1 && !a.whoIsWinning() && !a.isLpmRepeat(round-1))         {
                s.sSuper(a.PcWonLastRound, lastpcm);
            }
    // Тут нужно реализовать wait. 
            Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
            synchronized (th){
                try {
                    th.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            int plm = controller.getPcm(); // ход игрока
            int pcm = s.getPcm();
            System.out.println("\n\r");
            a.whoWon(plm, pcm);

            lastplm = plm;
            lastpcm = pcm;
            a.setPlayersMoves(round, plm); // добавляет ход игрока в коллекцию анализатора
            round++;
            a.showScore();


        }
    }


}
```

Вот часть кода для GUI, где необходимо реализовать notify() и возобновить главный поток.

```
class ButtonListener1 implements ActionListener {


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        controller.setPcm(0);
        Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
        synchronized (th) {
            th.notify();
            System.out.println("Ответ "+controller.getPcm());
        }


    }
}
class ButtonListener2 implements ActionListener {


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        controller.setPcm(1);
        Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
        synchronized (th) {
            th.notify();
            System.out.println("Ответ "+controller.getPcm());
        }


    }
}
class ButtonListener3 implements ActionListener {


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        controller.setPcm(2);
        Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
        synchronized (th) {
            th.notify();
            System.out.println("Ответ " + controller.getPcm());
        }

    }
}
```

И код контроллера

```
public class KNBController {
private int pcm;

public int getPcm() {
    return pcm;
}

public void setPcm(int pcm) {
    this.pcm = pcm;
}


}
```

Главный поток не возобновляется после получения ввода с кнопки... В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: GUI и так находится в постоянном ожидании событий. Можно запустить нужный метод по событию "нажата кнопка". Если надо выполнить что-то в другом потоке, то надо для начала запустить другой поток, а не заниматься самотыком в Thread.currentThread(); нудивительно, что ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать поток для синхронизации не очень хорошо. Тем более видно, что Вы даже не можете получить нужный поток, вместо этого крутите несчастный currentThread.
Что бы notify() wait() работали, надо вызывать их на одном и том же объекте. А currentThread как можно было бы догадаться в разных thread-ах будет разный.  notify() запускаете на одном, а wait() совсем на другом. В результате - фиг.

Гораздо выгодней использовать какой-то глобальный объект, который точно все знают.

```
public class KNBGameStarter {
    Object sync; // объект для синхронизации

    public KNBGameStarter(Object sync) {
        this.sync = sync;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Objecy sync = new Object(); // создаём глобальный объект
        KNBGameStarter game = new KNBGameStarter(sync); // распространяем его через конструктор
        KNBGui gui = new KNBGui();

        gui.guiStarter();
        game.gameLogic();
    }

    private void gameLogic() {
        ...
        while (true) {
            ...
            synchronized(sync) {
                ...
                sync.wait();
                ...
            } 
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Не знаю как `controller` оказался в `ActionListener`-е, но очевидно ничто не мешает таким же образом прокинуть туда и `sync`.

```
class ButtonListener1 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        controller.setPcm(0);
        synchronized (sync) {
           sync.notify();
           System.out.println("Ответ "+controller.getPcm());
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь notify() и wait() будут работать на одном и том же объекте sync.
Таким не хитрым образом можно задействовать и более продвинутые средства синхронизации.

И заметьте - никаких thread. Пусть себе thread-ят незаметно.

Не могу догадаться о его предназначении `controller`, но возможно в данном случае будет лучше задействовать его вместо `sync`.